# How do i limit zoom out in google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am trying to limit zoom out in google maps android so users cant zoom out and see all the world.Is this possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set `setMinZoomPreference(float value)` and `setMaxZoomPreference(float value)` with [Google Maps APIs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#changing_zoom_level_and_setting_minimummaximum_zoom)

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

mMap.setMinZoomPreference(6.0f); // Set a preference for minimum zoom (Zoom out).
mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(14.0f); // Set a preference for maximum zoom (Zoom In).
```

Comment: what does maximum minimum zoom means ? which one is limit for zoom out ?

Comment: It will set a preferred minimum and/or maximum zoom level for map. Have you read attached https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#changing_zoom_level_and_setting_minimummaximum_zoom  It will give you detail information. You can `setMinZoomPreference(float value)` for zoom out and `setMaxZoomPreference(float value)` for Zoom in.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to restrict the zoom in google maps.

Kotlin

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    googleMap.setMinZoomPreference(10f)
}
```

void [setMinZoomPreference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setMinZoomPreference(float))(float minZoomPreference)